# Topology induced bycone metric

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Is cone metric define atopology as same as the topology define by ametric?
I have tried to prove it by theorems that joined them

Comment: What's the cone metric? Also, every metric induces a topology generated by the open balls in the metric space. Is this what you need?

Comment: Let X be a nonempty set. Suppose the mapping d :X ×X→E satisfies
(d1) 0<d(x,y) for all x,y ∈ X and d(x, y) = 0 if and only if x = y;
(d2) d(x, y) = d(y, x) for all x,y ∈ X;
(d3) d(x, y)  d(x, z) +d(y, z) for all x, y, z ∈ X.
Then d is called a cone metric on X, and (X, d) is called a cone metric space

Comment: d3 has been miss-typed.

Comment: (d3) d(x, y)<d(x, z) +d(y, z) for all x, y, z ∈ X.

Comment: I assume by $<$ you mean some partial ordering? And is $E$ an ordered vector space?

Comment: I mean that every cone metric space is metric space and both define atoplogy my question is does both define same topology? and how i can prove that

Comment: Then what is $E$ and what is $<$?

Comment: E is a Banach space and < is partial ordering

Comment: In which case cone metric spaces are not metric spaces, except when $E=\mathbb{R}$ and $<$ is the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so does both satisfies same topology or not and why?

Answer (score 1):

On page 25 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4920) by Petko D. Proinov on the arXiv, it is proved that if $E$ is a solid vector space and $(X,d)$ is a cone metric space over $E$, then the open balls of $(X,d)$ form the basis of a topology of a metrisable topological space.

Answer (score 1):

Petko D. Proinov's result is about tvs-cone metric spaces (which is a generalization of cone metric spaces) so that result holds for cone metric spaces as well. It means that there is a homeomorphism between a cone metric space and a metric space, hence cone metric spaces and metric spaces are the same from the topological view.